# How to get wordpress document root where is wordpress installed from the plugins?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code

```
@include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/feed/wp-config.php');
global $table_prefix, $wpdb;   
$fbrepurp_scedule= $table_prefix ."fbrepurp_scedule";
```

its works fine but here is my wordpress into subfolder "feed" when my plugins install another site it will never works as i know

I triend to use

```
    $fpath = get_home_path();
$config_file =$fpath .'wp-config.php';
include_once($config_file);
```

But its not woks for me .
Pls give me a solution ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

At last i got my answer and it works fine for me

```
function fs_get_wp_config_path()
{
    $base = dirname(__FILE__);
    $path = false;

    if (@file_exists(dirname(dirname($base))."/wp-config.php"))
    {
        $path = dirname(dirname($base))."/wp-config.php";
    }
    else
    if (@file_exists(dirname(dirname(dirname($base)))."/wp-config.php"))
    {
        $path = dirname(dirname(dirname($base)))."/wp-config.php";
    }
    else
    $path = false;

    if ($path != false)
    {
        $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $path);
    }
    return $path;
}
```